# Loop through json array with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´ve got an array in this format:

```
var items = [{
        "link": {
            "0": "http://www.example.com/"
        },
        "title": {
            "0": "example"
        }
    }, {
        "link": {
            "0": "http://www.example2.com"
        },
        "title": {
            "0": "example2"
        }
    }]
```

I can´t figure out how to loop through it and display its values in HTML.

Im using jquery and have tried using an each-loop:

```
$.each( items, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '6271' in
    })
```

Help appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Your code works in the example i posted above. I will accept asasp.
I noticed however that the real json im trying to loop is not always properly formatted which leads to a crash:

```
var items = [{
        "link": {
            "0": "http://www.example.com/"
        },
        "title": {
            "0": "example"
        }
    }, {
        "link": {
            "0": "http://www.example2.com"
        },
        "title": {
            "0": "example2: "
            some text here ""
        }
    }]
```

When looping this array i get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is there a way to maybe skip all "broken" objects?

Comment: Are you sure that is the error message you are getting for the code you have shown. You are not using the "in" operator in your code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. It works for me without error.

Comment: what result you are expecting?

Comment: @louis9898 You updated JSON is incorrect

Comment: @bhspencer You are right. When correcting the ill formatted json it works with my original code. It is the badly formatted json that generates the: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @Shiladitya Yes! The json that I receive from the server is incorrect and that is what causes the error. Is there a way to skip the "bad" objects maybe?

Comment: @louis9898 No there is no way that you can skip it. You need to fix it in the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var items = [{
  "link": {
      "0": "http://www.example.com/"
  },
  "title": {
      "0": "example"
  }
}, {
  "link": {
      "0": "http://www.example2.com"
  },
  "title": {
      "0": "example2"
  }
}];

$.each( items, function(i, item) {
  $("body").append(`<span class="title">${item.title["0"]}:</span> <span>${item.link["0"]}</span><br/>`);
});
```

```css
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Each `item` is an object, to get the link value I've provided in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty:

```
for (item of items) {
  console.log(item.link[0])
  console.log(item.title[0])
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OPs code. They have just become confused. Their code works.

Comment: Don't forget to declare your `item` variable, preferably with `const`.